# sumproduct to sum total days

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

In a spreadsheet I have two columns, 1st - date opened, 2nd - date closed.

What I'm trying to do is sum the total number of days where a file is not closed.

Using the following formulas, I can count the number of files that are still open;

```
=COUNTIFS(Data!L5:L6000,">0",Data!M5:M6000,"")
```

or

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(Data!L5:L6000>0),(--(Data!M5:M6000="")))
```

Is there anyway to expand either of these to return the **sum** of the number of days from today, where the file is still open?  Can this be done as an array formula perhaps?

Thanks

Comment: can you provide some sample data and expected result?

Comment: I would add another column that displays the days a file is open, and use sumifs to sum that column in case it is opened.

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys. @Luuklag, unfortunately I'm unable to alter the data structure due to restrictions on that sheet, so I'm trying to calculate the result in one formula if possible in another worksheet.

Comment: An example of what I need is where there is a date in Column L, and the corresponding cell in Column M is blank.  Where this happens, I want to know how many days have lapsed since the date in Column L.  Something like =Today() - L7, but to sum over the entire range e.g. L7 value = 14/02/2017 and L12 value  = 18/01/2017.  From today, the value for each using Today() - cellvalue = 77 & 104.  The returned value would be 181.  Hope this helps

Comment: @Luuklag, That does the job nicely!  Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `=Sumproduct((Data!M5:M6000="")*(Today()-Data!L5:L6000))`